# AWK merge values and replace strings

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files one separated by tabs and other separated by semicolons. Both files have a common ID in the first column. On the one hand I want to combine the values in column 3 based on a common ID. On the other hand I want to replace the string in column 2 of the first file with the string in column 2 of the second file, while respecting the Common ID.

First file:

```
ID;String;Category;
2;es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien;321;0;;
3;es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse;72;0;;
4;es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.;52;0;;
4;es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.;70;0;;
5;credito pyme banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio;50;0;;
5;credito pyme banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio;52;0;;
5;credito pyme banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio;70;0;;
5;credito pyme banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio;71;0;;
```

Second file:

```
ID    String    Category;
2   Es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien.
3   Es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse.
4   Es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.
5   Credito Pyme Banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio.
```

Desired output:

```
ID    String    Category
2   Es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien. 321
3   Es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse.   72
4   Es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.   52  70
5   Credito Pyme Banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio.  50  52  70  71
```

What I have done:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=";";} NR==FNR{ CAT[$1]=CAT[$1]"\t"$3; next;}{FS="\t";textos[$1]=$2;} END{ for (ID in CAT) {print ID,textos[ID],CAT[ID];}}' fileA fileB
```

My Output:

```
2   Es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien.
3   Es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse.   72
4   Es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.   52   70
5   Credito Pyme Banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio   50   52   70   71
¡¡In the first line the value of the third column doesn't appear!!
```

Comment: Any particular reason we need to be subjected to so many lines and such long lines of input? I don't see why you couldn't express your question with, say 5 lines of input, each line with 5 fields. If you can't get your examples down to a concise size with simple fields I doubt if many people will bother trying to understand it so they can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks! for your suggestion, it's better understood now?

Comment: Yes, much but I see you already accepted an answer so it didn't give many experts time to look at your question and try to help you. FWIW the answer you selected violates awk's variable naming conventions, sets `FS` in the wrong place (the functional error is hidden by your 1st line being a header and otherwise it's just inefficient), contains redundant code, has spurious trailing semi-colons and will produce a syntax error when run by some awks. Good luck!

Comment: @Ed Morton If you read the reviews, my problem is not yet resolved. Could you spend some of your time and wisdom to give me a right solution ?. Thank you!

Comment: You have already selected an answer so work with the author of that answer to enhance their solution. No-one, including me, is going to bother trying to provide other answers when you already have selected one and it seems like there's things about your problem you haven't told us about in your question so no-one wants to deal with the frustration of peeling an onion to try to figure out what it is you want that you haven't told us about.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, thanks! for your kindness! Sorry! to be a waste of time for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR {
   a[$1] = a[$1] OFS $3
   next
}
FNR==1 {
   FS="\t"
   print
}
$1 in a {
   print $1, $2 a[$1]
}' file1 file2
```

**Output:**

```
ID  String  Category
2   Es un anuncio interesante que le puede servir para alguien. 321
3   Es un anuncio de un banco que quiere presentarse.   72
4   Es un anuncio de un banco que ofrece prestamos para empresas.   52  70
5   Credito Pyme Banamex para hacer crecer tu negocio.  50  52  70  71
```

Comment: I have to fill out column 2 of the first file with column 2 of the second file. By matching the ID!

Comment: Thanks! now the text in column 2 is correct. But the first line (ID 2) is not printed.

Comment: Okay, but .. it is missing the value of the third column. Which in this case would be 321

Comment: Well, I don't know why, but when I run your awk, the first line of the file2 is skipped. If I double that line in file2, the output is correct.

Comment: I've copied your sample data from question itself and `321` appears in 1st line of output both using gnu-awk and BSD-awk. Make sure your 2nd file head header row and it is all tab delimited.

Comment: Forgive myself you all!! I'm dumb in my testing I wasn't including the header. "ID  String  Category"